# When I open the spyder in anaconda, the spyder indicates that an error ocurred while starting the kernel in spyder

Tags: python, kernel, spyder

When I open the Spyder in anaconda, the Spyder indicates that an error occurred while starting the kernel in Spyder. I have tried (in the terminal) two suggested commands from Spyder. However, after I restart anaconda and open Spyder, the same problem exists, so I don't know how to solve the problem. Thank you for your help!

Below is what Spyder says when opened:

```
An error occurred while starting the kernel

Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed. Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.

You can install it by running in a system terminal:

conda install spyder‑kernels=0.*

or

pip install spyder‑kernels==0.*
```

The results in the terminal are listed below.

```
(base) pn-204-190:~ yangboning$ conda install spyder-kernels=0.*
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

(base) pn-204-190:~ yangboning$ pip install spyder-kernels==0.*
Requirement already satisfied: spyder-kernels==0.* in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel>=4.8.2 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spyder-kernels==0.*) (5.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: wurlitzer; platform_system != "Windows" in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spyder-kernels==0.*) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spyder-kernels==0.*) (18.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spyder-kernels==0.*) (1.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=5.2.3 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spyder-kernels==0.*) (5.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.1.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (4.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=5.0.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (7.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4.2 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (6.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.2.3->spyder-kernels==0.*) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.2.3->spyder-kernels==0.*) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.1.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.1.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.1.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (0.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (2.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: appnope; sys_platform == "darwin" in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (41.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (4.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parso>=0.5.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jedi>=0.10->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pexpect; sys_platform != "win32"->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels==0.*) (0.6.0)
(base) pn-204-190:~ yangboning$
```

Answer (score 3):

If the solution by @lyq didn't work, this worked for me.

Open Anaconda prompt and run this line:

```
spyder --reset
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
conda install spyder-kernels
```

or

```
pip install spyder-kernels
```

Comment: Aha, finally I uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda then the problem didn't exist anymore. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Check for a compatible version of spyder-kernel from [here](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/troubleshooting/common-illnesses.html) and install using pip like this-

`pip install spyder-kernels== COMPATIBLE VERSION`

Answer (score 0):

Also, installing matplotlib solved the issue for me.